# draw multiple lines passing from one point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have one point and I am passing multiple lines from it using `matplotlib.pyplot.axline`. I know it plots infinitely long straight lines but I want to limit length of line.

```py
def seq(start, stop, step=1):
    n = int(round((stop - start)/float(step)))
    # print([n])
    if n > 1:
        a = [start + step*i for i in range(n+1)]
        round_a = [round(num, 2) for num in a]
        return (round_a)
    elif n == 1:
        return([start])
    else:
        return([])

c=seq(-50, 50, 5)


for i in range(0,len(c)):

    plt.scatter(55.0, 450.1,color='black',s=500)
    plt.axline((55.0, 450.1),slope=c[i],color='red')
```

output:

[image]

what I want:
length of line till the oval from point

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more mathematic than programming. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```py
r = 10    
x = np.linspace(-r, r, 1000)
# x**2 + y**2 = r**2
# (x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 = r**2
# y**2 = r - x**2
y = (r**2 - x**2)**0.5

plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
ax.plot(x, y, 'k')
ax.plot(x, -y, 'k')

a = np.linspace(-r, r, 9)
# r = (a**2 + b**2)**0.5
# r**2 = a**2 + b**2
# b**2 = r**2 - a**2
# b = (r**2 - a**2)**0.5
b = (r**2 - a**2)**0.5
    
for i in range(len(a)):
    ax.plot([a[i], a[-i-1]], [b[i], -b[-i-1]], 'r')
```

Output:

[image]

```
r = 10    
x = np.linspace(-r, r, 1000)
y = (r**2 - x**2)**0.5

plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
ax.plot(x+55, y+450, 'k')
ax.plot(x+55, -y+450, 'k')

a = np.linspace(-r, r, 9)
b = (r**2 - a**2)**0.5
    
for i in range(len(a)):
    ax.plot([a[i]+55, a[-i-1]+55], [b[i]+450, -b[-i-1]+450], 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: how can i change the x,y values of point which is at the center (0,0) to  55, 450.1 .  means the  center must be 55,450.1

Comment: That's math. As I have included in the code above, the equation for a circle is ``(x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 = r**2``, with ``a`` and ``b`` the shift of the center point.

Comment: what do you mean empty space at the left and right side? What's wrong with my latest edit in my answer? I moved the center point to ``(55, 450)`` as you requested already

Comment: look at the upper and lower area multiple lines are there but at left and right thery are not . example from 55,450.1 to 452.5 and to 447.5

Comment: You mean the density of the line? That's the ``9`` in ``a = np.linspace(-r, r, 9)``. The number of lines you want +1.